# Is there a way of making the first part of formatted string bold?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way of making "${innerItem.key}" bold? Thanks

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> incidentList = [
                    for (final json in listNode.map((x) => x.toJson()))
                      {
                        'Code': json['field'][0]['field_value'],
                        'Description': json['field'][1]['field_value'],
                        'Organisation Unit': json['field'][2]['field_value'],
                        'Date Reported': json['field'][3]['field_value'],
                        'Status': json['field'][4]['field_value'],
                        'RunHyperlink' : json['run_hyperlink']
                      }
                  ];

                  final List<String> values =  [];
                  for(final item in incidentList){
                    String groupedElement = "";
                    for(var innerItem in item.entries)
                    {

                      groupedElement += "${innerItem.key}  : ${innerItem.value}\n";
                    }
                    values.add(groupedElement);
                  }

                  await WriteCache.setListString(key: 'cache4', value: values);


                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LossEvent()));
```

The string will be stored in "values" and will then be accessed by "snapshot.data[index]". Is there a way of making "${innerItem.key} bold?" before storing it into "values"?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `RichText`:

```
Text.rich(
  TextSpan(
    children: [
      TextSpan(
        text: "${innerItem.key}: ",
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      TextSpan(text: "${innerItem.value}\n"),
    ],
  ),
)
```

And of course, it will have to be a list of `Widget`, and not string

Comment: thanks for the answer but, I am storing the string in "values" and sending it to another page and from that page I am accessing the string using "snapshot.data[index]" is there a way of making "${innerItem.key}" bold before storing it in "values" I have updated my question with the full code.

Comment: @JoshuaaMarkk then you should probably store the JSON in the cache, and parse it before you display, and not before you store it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [flutter_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html) package and the to put a String with HTML format

ex:

```dart
Html(
  data: '<body><b>This text is gonna be bold</b><br>This gonna be normal</body>',
  style: {
            'body': Style(
              fontSize: 18,
            ),
            'b': Style(
              fontSize: 18,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
);
```

Also, you can customize the styling of your text using HTML tags(or your custom tags) from styles Map property.

To implement the html tags in the groupElement, just do it like this:

```dart
for(var innerItem in item.entries)
                    {

                      groupedElement += "<body><b>${innerItem.key}</b>  : ${innerItem.value}\n</body>";
                    }
                    values.add(groupedElement);
```

I don't know why you use the '\n' but you can replace it with the break line html tag 
 if it suits you

Comment: thanks for the answer but, I am storing the string in "values" and sending it to another page and from that page I am accessing the string using "snapshot.data[index]" is there a way of making "${innerItem.key}" bold before storing it in "values" I have updated my question with the full code.

Comment: Of course there is a way with the Html tags, I've just updated my answer, please, take a look into the second code snippet